# which one is better to use SignalR or requestanimationframe?

Tags: signalr, requestanimationframe

I have been developing an application which contains instant notifications but I am a little confused about what is the best to use to get instant notifications, is it better to use the client side `requestanimationframe` method or to use `signalR`?.

so please could anyone explain which one should I use and why.

Comment: You can easily do that with SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the best use cases for `SignalR`. Create a `Hub` on which you connect your client and send notifications from there.

You can have a look here - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/672433/Real-time-Notifications-with-SignalR

Hope this helps! Best of luck!